# Set Excel cells or formula to background or low-priority recalculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, multi-threaded

I have an Excel worksheet with a column of non-volatile formulas that are computationally expensive but low priority.  So I don't care if they update infrequently, and would prefer that they do so in the background so as not to preempt the UI or any other high-priority calculations.

Is there any means of suggesting this to Excel?

I would hope there is a worksheet function like `=BACKGROUND({EXPENSIVE_FORMULA})` ... but knowing Excel I consider that unlikely.

Next closest guess is that there might be a way to use VBA to update those cell values on a background thread with some frequency?

---

Sample formula for each of ~300 rows.  Referenced cells are either frequently updated by RTD, or else also contain non-volatile arithmetic formulas:

`=V2*(1+EXP(($A$150/10000-AW2*(U2/AY2-1))/AV2-AX2-BA2)*(1+P2)-1)`.

Comment: Use non-volatile formula that only calculate when the preceding data changes.  My guess is that those expensive formula are volatile and calculate when ever there is a change to Excel.

Comment: I haven't heard of such a formula, but you might want to look into VBA like range.calculate.  You can find some information following this link. .https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation

Comment: @ScottCraner no they are non-volatile formulas.

Comment: can you show an example of the expensive formula?  But then you are correct the only way is move them into vba that you run when the desired condition is met.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just added example.  I can set a callback timer in VBA, but I don't know how to run a VBA callback function on a background thread.

Comment: 300 rows of maths formulas like your example shouldn't really be an issue. It's much more likely that the delays are coming from your RTD functions. You could turn all worksheet calculation off and periodically recalculate only those cells but you cannot turn off autocalculation for a portion of the worksheet.